# html ordering selection menu total

Tags: php, html, css

Hey guys i got a selecting/ordering code from a friend. But some parts are not working. I would be grateful if anyone of you could help me.

First of all i am not sure how to do this: I want the selected products to show up at the end in a summary of the order. Then i want the price of the selected product and as last the total amount it will cost.

```
<h3>Product 1: Name product 1:price product 1<br></h3>

<h3>Product 2: Name product 2:price product 2<br></h3>

<h3>Product 3: Name Product 3:price product 3<br></h3>

<h3>Total price: price product 1+price product 2+price product 3</h3>
```

Second of all i would like the pictures to be dynamic. They should change when the selected product changes.

example product 1 is selected it will show product 1 
Product 2 gets selected it will change to a picture of product 2.

```
<div class="partselectfoto partselectfoto_2462_id" style="display: block;">
                                                                <div class="part-images-slider"> <a class="active" href="uploads/images/cooler-master-k350-rood_1385639600.png" title="Budget Gaming PC" class="fancybox part-foto active" rel="group_2462">

                                      <img src="uploads/images/cooler-master-k350-rood_1385639600_120x120.png?f" title="Budget Gaming PC" alt="Budget Gaming PC" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;">
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/4s1yhytk/3/)

HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" type="text/css" href="/Copy/style.css"
</head>

<body>
    <div id="container">
                        <div id="body">
                            <div class="content_left">
                                <div class="content_area webshop">
                                    <div class="article last">
                                        <form action="handle/webshop" method="POST" name="webshop">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="art_price" value="339.00">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="art_discount" value="0.00">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="art_btw" value="21">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="art_id" value="573">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addarticle"> <a name="samenstellen"></a>

                                            <div class="part_category">
                                                <div class="partselecttypebox parttypeselect-casing">
                                                    <div class="left">
                                                        <div class="partselectfoto partselectfoto_2001_id" style="display: block;">
                                                            <div class="part-images-slider"> <a class="active" href="uploads/images/cooler-master-k350-rood_1385639600.png" title="Budget Gaming PC" class="fancybox part-foto active" rel="group_2001">

                                  <img src="uploads/images/cooler-master-k350-rood_1385639600_120x120.png?f" title="Budget Gaming PC" alt="Budget Gaming PC" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;">
                                  <div class="enlarge"></div>
                                </a>

                                                            </div>
                                                            <ul class="part-images-slider-bullets">
                                                                <li> <a href="#" class="active"></a>

                                                                </li>
                                                                <li> <a href="#" class=""></a>

                                                                </li>
                                                                <li> <a href="#" class=""></a>

                                                                </li>
                                                                <li> <a href="#" class=""></a>

                                                                </li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--left-->
                                                    <br>
                                                    <div class="right">
                                                         <h4>Product 1</h4>

                                                        <input type="radio" class="partselect" id="part_2001" name="parts[493]" value="2001" checked="checked">
                                                        <label for="part_2001" class="part_label"><span class="parttitle">Cooler Master K-350&nbsp;</span>
 <span class="floatleft marginleft" id="part_2001_pricelabel">Price</span>

                                                        </label>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_2001_price" value="0">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_2001_category" value="493">
                                                        <br>
                                                        <input type="radio" class="partselect" id="part_2002" name="parts[493]" value="2002">
                                                        <label for="part_2002" class="part_label"><span class="parttitle">Cooler Master K-380&nbsp;</span>
 <span class="floatleft marginleft" id="part_2002_pricelabel">Price</span>

                                                        </label>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_2002_price" value="0">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_2002_category" value="493">
                                                        <br>
                                                        <br>
                                                        <p></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--right-->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- partselect-->
                                                <div class="partselecttypebox">
                                                    <!-- Start partselect-->
                                                    <div class="left">
                                                        <div class="partselectfoto partselectfoto_1510_id" style="display: block;"> <a href="uploads/images/amd-fm2-a4-5300-dual-core-34ghz.jpg" title="Budget Gaming PC" class="fancybox part-foto" rel="group_1510">
                                <img src="uploads/images/amd-fm2-a4-5300-dual-core-34ghz_120x120.jpg?f" title="Budget Gaming PC" alt="Budget Gaming PC" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;">
                                <div class="enlarge"></div>
                              </a>

                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="partselectfotohidden partselectfoto_1511_id"> <a href="uploads/images/amd-fm2-a6-6400k-dual-core-39ghz_1371813079.jpg" title="Budget Gaming PC" class="fancybox part-foto" rel="group_1511">
                                <img src="uploads/images/amd-fm2-a6-6400k-dual-core-39ghz_1371813079_120x120.jpg?f" title="Budget Gaming PC" alt="Budget Gaming PC" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;">
                                <div class="enlarge"></div>
                              </a>

                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <br>
                                                    <div class="right">
                                                         <h4>Product 2</h4>

                                                        <input type="radio" class="partselect" id="part_1510" name="parts[491]" value="1510" checked="checked">
                                                        <label for="part_1510" class="part_label"><span class="parttitle">AMD FM2 A4-5300 Dual Core 3,4GHz&nbsp;</span>
 <span class="floatleft marginleft" id="part_1510_pricelabel">Price</span>

                                                        </label>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_1510_price" value="0">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_1510_category" value="491">
                                                        <br>
                                                        <input type="radio" class="partselect" id="part_1511" name="parts[491]" value="1511">
                                                        <label for="part_1511" class="part_label"><span class="parttitle">AMD FM2 A6-6400K Dual Core 3,9GHz&nbsp;</span>
 <span class="floatleft marginleft" id="part_1511_pricelabel">Price</span>

                                                        </label>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_1511_price" value="28">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_1511_category" value="491">
                                                        <br>
                                                        <br>
                                                        <p></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--right-->
                                                </div>
                                                <!-- partselect-->
                                                <div class="partselecttypebox">
                                                    <!-- Start partselect-->
                                                    <div class="left">
                                                        <div class="partselectfoto partselectfoto_1524_id">
                                                            <img src="uploads/images/standaard-koeling_120x120.jpg?f" class="part-foto" title="Budget Gaming PC" alt="Budget Gaming PC" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;">
                                                        </div>
                                                        <div class="partselectfotohidden partselectfoto_1525_id">
                                                            <div class="part-images-slider"> <a href="uploads/images/stille-pc-koeling_1401788514.jpg" title="Budget Gaming PC" class="fancybox part-foto active" rel="group_1525">
                                  <img src="uploads/images/stille-pc-koeling_1401788514_120x120.jpg?f" title="Budget Gaming PC" alt="Budget Gaming PC" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;">
                                  <div class="enlarge"></div>
                                </a>
 <a href="uploads/images/stille-pc-koeling1_1401788516.jpg" title="Budget Gaming PC" class="fancybox part-foto" rel="group_1525">
                                  <img src="uploads/images/stille-pc-koeling1_1401788516_120x120.jpg?f" title="Budget Gaming PC" alt="Budget Gaming PC" style="width: 120px; height: 120px;">
                                  <div class="enlarge"></div>
                                </a>

                                                            </div>
                                                            <ul class="part-images-slider-bullets">
                                                                <li> <a href="#" class="active"></a>

                                                                </li>
                                                                <li> <a href="#" class=""></a>

                                                                </li>
                                                                <li> <a href="#" class=""></a>

                                                                </li>
                                                            </ul>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--left-->
                                                    <br>
                                                    <div class="right">
                                                         <h4>Product 3</h4>

                                                        <input type="radio" class="partselect" id="part_1524" name="parts[717]" value="1524" checked="checked">
                                                        <label for="part_1524" class="part_label"><span class="parttitle">Standaard koeling&nbsp;</span>
 <span class="floatleft marginleft" id="part_1524_pricelabel"></span>

                                                        </label>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_1524_price" value="0">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_1524_category" value="717">
                                                        <br>
                                                        <input type="radio" class="partselect" id="part_1525" name="parts[717]" value="1525">
                                                        <label for="part_1525" class="part_label"><span class="parttitle">Stille koeling(Cooler Master TX3 evo)&nbsp;</span>
 <span class="floatleft marginleft" id="part_1525_pricelabel">Price</span>

                                                        </label>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_1525_price" value="25">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_1525_category" value="717">
                                                        <br>
                                                        <input type="radio" class="partselect" id="part_2096" name="parts[717]" value="2096">
                                                        <label for="part_2096" class="part_label"><span class="parttitle">Fluisterstille koeling(Cooler Master Hyper 412S)&nbsp;</span>
 <span class="floatleft marginleft" id="part_2096_pricelabel">Price</span>

                                                        </label>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_2096_price" value="39">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_2096_category" value="717">
                                                        <br>
                                                        <input type="radio" class="partselect" id="part_2504" name="parts[717]" value="2504">
                                                        <label for="part_2504" class="part_label"><span class="parttitle">Waterkoeling Corsair Hydro H80i&nbsp;</span>
 <span class="floatleft marginleft" id="part_2504_pricelabel">Price</span>

                                                        </label>
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_2504_price" value="99">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="part_2504_category" value="717">
                                                        <br>
                                                        <br>
                                                        <p></p>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <!--right-->
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <br>
                                            <div class="total">
                                                    <h2>Total</h2>

                            <h3>Product 1: Name product 1:price product 1<br></h3>

                            <h3>Product 2: Name product 2:price product 2<br></h3>

                            <h3>Product 3: Name Product 3:price product 3<br></h3>

                            <h3>Total price: price product 1+price product 2+price product 3</h3>

                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
<code>
html,
body,
div,
span,
applet,
object,
iframe,
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6,
p,
blockquote,
pre,
a,
abbr,
acronym,
address,
big,
cite,
code,
del,
dfn,
em,
img,
ins,
kbd,
q,
s,
samp,
small,
strike,
strong,
sub,
sup,
tt,
var,
b,
u,
i,
center,
dl,
dt,
dd,
ol,
ul,
li,
fieldset,
form,
label,
legend,
table,
caption,
tbody,
tfoot,
thead,
tr,
th,
td,
article,
aside,
canvas,
details,
embed,
figure,
figcaption,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
output,
ruby,
section,
summary,
time,
mark,
audio,
video {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font: inherit;
  vertical-align: baseline
}
article,
aside,
details,
figcaption,
figure,
footer,
header,
hgroup,
menu,
nav,
section {
  display: block
}
body {
  line-height: 1
}
ol,
ul {
  list-style: none
}
blockquote,
q {
  quotes: none
}
blockquote:before,
blockquote:after,
q:before,
q:after {
  content: '';
  content: none
}
table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  border-spacing: 0
}
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none
}
body,
html {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 13px;
  line-height: 19px;
  color: #5a5a5a
}
body {} table th,
td {
  vertical-align: top
}
strong,
b {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: Arial;
  color: #000
}
p {
  margin-bottom: 15px
}
p img[align="left"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 20px 10px 0
}
p img[align="right"] {
  display: block;
  margin: 5px 0 10px 20px
}
img a:hover {
  cursor: pointer
}
object,
embed {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 14px;
  padding: 0
}
li {
  margin: 0 0 0 21px
}
a {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  outline: none;
  border: 0;
  color: #005FA3;
  text-decoration: underline
}
h1,
h2,
h3,
h4,
h5,
h6 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 14px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000
}
h1 {
  display: block;
  margin: 14px 0 2px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 25px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000
}
h2 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 7px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 25px;
  line-height: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000
}
h3 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 14px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 22px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000
}
h4 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 14px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #000
}
h5 {
  display: block;
  margin: 0 0 14px 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 19px;
  font-weight: bold
}
h6 {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px 0 20px 0;
  padding: 0 0 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ebebeb;
  font-size: 24px;
  line-height: 39px;
  font-weight: 300
}
h6 a {
  display: inline-block;
  margin: 0 7px 0 0;
  padding: 0
}
bodybar {
  width: 100%
}
body {
  clear: both;
  display: block;
  width: 980px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background-color: #fff
}
.part_category {
  padding: 0 0 14px 0;
  overflow: hidden
}
.partselecttypebox {
  overflow: hidden;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  border-top: 1px solid #c2c2c2
}
.partselecttypebox .left {
  float: left;
  width: 120px;
  margin-right: 28px;
  margin-top: 7px;
  margin-bottom: 14px;
  position: relative
}
.partselecttypebox .right {
  overflow: hidden;
  padding: 14px 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  line-height: 17px
}
.partselecttypebox .right .module_top h4 {
  font-size: 15px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #000
}
.part_label .parttitle {
  display: block;
  clear: none;
  float: left;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 0 0 0 9px
}
.partselect {
  float: left;
  clear: both;
  margin: 3px 0 0 0
}
label.part_label {} label.part_label:hover,
label.part_label:focus {
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #e40101
}
.partselectfoto,
.partselectfotohidden {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0
}
.partselectfotohidden {
  display: none
}
.partcategoryfoto {
  opacity: 0.5
}
.partselectfoto
```

I am not sure if i have posted this in the right way sorry if i didnt.
Thanks for reading.

Comment: Holy Codedump Batman! Just make a short self contained example - http://www.sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

You are using way too many divs and a lot of them don't even exist in your CSS file. I'm not sure if you're a beginner but you might want to fix that and you may not run into so many problems.